# how to select multiple Images in checkbox in recycle view Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

```
 from kivy.uix.modalview import ModalView    
 from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen    
 from kivymd.app import MDApp   
 from kivy.metrics import dp    
 from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

KV = """ 
<ImgCard@ButtonBehavior+BoxLayout>
    path: ""
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    Image:
        source: root.path
        size_hint_y: .9
    MDCheckbox:
 
<Gallery> 
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
        RecycleView:
            id: img_base
            viewclass: "ImgCard"
            canvas.before:
                #$#Color:
                #$rgba: (.4, .4, .4, .7)
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            RecycleGridLayout:
                spacing: 10 
                cols: 3
                default_size: None, dp(48)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                multiselect: True
                touch_multiselect: True     """
class ImageManager(ModalView):
    pass

class Gallery(Screen):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)

    self.manager_list = []
    self.dir = os.getcwd()
    self.available_image_format = ['.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.bmp']  # etc

def load_images(self):
    if not self.manager_list:
        for image in os.listdir(self.dir):
            target_filename, target_file_extension = os.path.splitext(image)
            if target_file_extension in self.available_image_format:
                path_to_image = os.path.join(self.dir, image)
                self.manager_list.append(
                    {
                        "ImgCard": "ImageManager",
                        "path": path_to_image,
                        "height": dp(200),
                    }
                )
        self.ids.img_base.data = self.manager_list
        self.images=[self.dir]

class GalleryApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        return Gallery()
    
    def on_start(self):
        self.root.load_images()
    

if __name__=='__main__':
    GalleryApp().run()
```

How to link checkbox in gallery for also multiple select in kivy. Can anyone help this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `MDCheckbox` in a `RecycleView`, then you should include the `state` of that `MDCheckbox` in the `data`. If you don't do that, then the `RecyclView` doesn't know about the `state` of the `MDCheckbox` and when an `MDCheckbox` gets recycled, its `state` will be whatever it was last time it was used.
To accomplish that, first modify your `kv` rule for `ImgCard`:

```
<ImgCard@BoxLayout>
    path: ""
    selected: False  # added to indicate selection
    index: -1  # added to enable accessing this item in the data
    orientation: "vertical"
    size_hint_y: None
    Image:
        source: root.path
        size_hint_y: .9
    MDCheckbox:
        id: cb
        state: 'down' if root.selected else 'normal'
        on_release: app.root.adjust_data(root)
```

Note that the `ButtonBehavior` is not necessary.

Then, modify the initial `data` to initialize the new properties:

```
def load_images(self):
    count = 0
    if not self.manager_list:
        for image in os.listdir(self.dir):
            target_filename, target_file_extension = os.path.splitext(image)
            if target_file_extension in self.available_image_format:
                path_to_image = os.path.join(self.dir, image)
                self.manager_list.append(
                    {
                        "ImgCard": "ImageManager",
                        "path": path_to_image,
                        "height": dp(200),
                        "selected": False,
                        "index": count
                    }
                )
                count += 1
        self.ids.img_base.data = self.manager_list
        self.images = [self.dir]
```

And add a method in the `Gallery` class to update the `data` when a `MDCheckbox` is changed:

```
def adjust_data(self, imgcard):
    rv = self.ids.img_base
    rv.data[imgcard.index]['selected'] = imgcard.ids.cb.state == 'down'
    imgcard.ids.cb.state = 'normal'
    rv.refresh_from_data()
```

To remove the selected items, you can add a `Button` in your `<Gallery>` rule that calls:

```
def delete(self, instance):
    rv = self.ids.img_base
    deleted = False
    for i in range(len(rv.data) - 1, -1, -1):
        item = rv.data[i]
        if item['selected']:
            del rv.data[i]
            deleted = True
    if deleted:
        self.adjust_indices()
```

Since deleting any items will upset the `index` property of items in the `data`, another method is required to adjust the `index` properties:

```
def adjust_indices(self):
    # adjust index values to account for removd items
    rv = self.ids.img_base
    index = 0
    for item in rv.data:
        item['index'] = index
        index += 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot John Sir! Can i ask something in that codes? I don't want to add in `ImgCard` so adding with that `Gallery`. So here's my code- `MDFloatingActionButton:
            icon: "delete"
           on_release:app.root.delete(root)`  but isn't working , here's delete code- `def delete(self, instance):
        for item in self.ids.img_base.data:
            if item['path'] == instance.path:
                self.ids.img_base.data.remove(item)
                return` .Thanks again...

Comment: That code seems to wok for me. Perhaps you should post that as another question along with the current state of your code.